# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:\windows\sun\java\deployment\trusted.cacerts

Tags: java, testng

I'm new to the stack exchange forum.

I'm trying to execute a test in Java using testNG. To give you a brief background, I'm executing the java package through an xml file and running the package as a TestNG Suite. I am also going through a VPN and have passed the arguments in to the run configurations. When I try to run any test I receive the following error:

## Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Picked up

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:\windows\sun\java\deployment\trusted.cacerts
```

I have executed this test successfully before, and I'm not sure what changed. Let me know if you have seen this seen this issue before. Also, let me know if you need any more details, or if you have any questions. I'll take all the help I can get at this point.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to figure out what is going on. Please add some source code, suite xml etc., that will add a bit more context to your problem.

Comment: Seems that your are skipping your maven tests ... but you must be more precise to get a clear answer

Comment: I was able to find the issue. I had @Test ( dataProvider = "deviceList", enabled=false)
    public void navigateTest( DeviceContainer dC ) {
        System.out.println(url);
  executeSteps( new Step[] { new Navigate(url), 
               new HomePageNavSteps(),
               new TimedNavigate(url, 4000),
               
        } );
   I had it enabled to false...my bad.